# Unsupported type for binding argument error in snowflake stored procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is the code for my stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test1(source_name VARCHAR,wf_name VARCHAR,wf_start_time datetime,wf_end_time datetime,wf_status VARCHAR,wf_flag VARCHAR)
    RETURNS VARCHAR
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS
    $$
      
    var cmd = `INSERT INTO DATA.IWX_JOB_LOG
               (SOURCE,
               WF_NAME,
               WF_START_TIME,
               WF_END_TIME,
               WF_STATUS
               )
               
               SELECT
               (?,?,date(?),date(?),?);`
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
              {
              sqlText: cmd,
              binds: [SOURCE_NAME,WF_NAME,WF_START_TIME,WF_END_TIME,WF_STATUS]
              }
              );
    var result1 = stmt.execute();


$$
;
```

```
CALL test1('test','test',getdate(),getdate(),'running','I')
```

here is my table :

| name | type |
| --- | --- |
| SOURCE | varchar(50), |
| WF_NAME | varchar(50), |
| WF_START_TIME | datetime, |
| WF_END_TIME | datetime , |
| WF_STATUS | varchar(50) |

getting error :

> Execution error in stored procedure TEST1: Unsupported type for binding argument 2undefined At Snowflake.createStatement, line 13 position 21

What I am doing wrong here? I need to get `current_date` in my date column.

Comment: Hi - please format your code as code so it is readable. Please don’t use images, use editable text (so that someone can copy it if they need to).

Answer (score 0):

The default Javascript `Date.toString()` representation converts the date to a string in a format that is not recognized by Snowflake, as it is not standard.

It returns the data in the following format:

```
$ node
> const event = new Date('March 15, 2023 10:20:30');
undefined
> console.log(event.toString());
Wed Mar 15 2023 10:20:30 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
undefined
>
```

Snowflake does not accept this date format, therefore fails with the error mentioned.

To fix the error use `Date.toISOString()` function to convert the Date into a format that is accepted by Snowflake.

This works fine for me:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test_1 (source varchar, wf_name varchar, wf_start_time datetime, wf_end_time datetime, wf_status varchar);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test1(source_name VARCHAR,wf_name VARCHAR,wf_start_time datetime,wf_end_time datetime,wf_status VARCHAR)
    RETURNS VARCHAR
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS
    $$
      
    var cmd = `INSERT INTO test_1 (SOURCE, WF_NAME, WF_START_TIME, WF_END_TIME, WF_STATUS) SELECT ?,?,date(?),date(?),?`
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
              { sqlText: cmd,
              binds: [SOURCE_NAME, WF_NAME, WF_START_TIME.toISOString(),WF_END_TIME.toISOString(), WF_STATUS]
              });
    var result1 = stmt.execute();
$$
;
CALL test1('test','test', getdate(), getdate(), 'running');
```

Pay attention also to the SELECT inside the procedure:

```
SELECT ?,?,date(?),date(?),?
```

and not

```
SELECT (?,?,date(?),date(?),?)
```

as if you use the second form you will encounter another error like:

```
SQL compilation error:
Insert value list does not match column list expecting 5 but got 1
At Statement.execute, line 8 position 23
```

Hope this helps. Also have a look at this Community [article](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Stored-Procedure-with-Date-parameter-failed-with-error-Unsupported-type-for-binding-argument-2).